# How to merge audio and video file of any format

Tags: android, audio, kotlin

I am developing an application for android in which I have a video and then I get a list of music from user phones I am able to get both of these, my problem is that now I want to combine the audio selected by user with video like a background music in the video, the video has no sound in it. Please Help me achieve this. I am sorry for the code posting the code not neatly because it's my first time writing a problem.

I have tried media muxer but it seems it doesn't support mp3 format, and since I am getting audio from users phone, it can be in any format.

**This is my music object class:**

```
class MusicMP3 : Serializable {
var isCheck: Boolean = false
var namemusic: String? = null
var namesong: String? = null
var path: String? = null


constructor(check: Boolean, namemusic: String, namesong: String, path: 
String) {
    this.isCheck = check
    this.namemusic = namemusic
    this.namesong = namesong
    this.path = path
}


}
```

**I am getting audio using this code:**

```
    musicArray = ArrayList<MusicMP3>()
    val contentResolver = contentResolver
    val songUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val songCursor = contentResolver.query(songUri!!, null, null, null, 
    null)
    if (songUri != null && songCursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
        val songTitle = 
     songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)
        val songArtist = 
     songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
        val songPath = 
     songCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)
        do {
            val currentTitle = songCursor.getString(songTitle)
            val currentArtist = songCursor.getString(songArtist)
            val currentPath = songCursor.getString(songPath)
            lsmusic!!.add(MusicMP3(false, currentTitle, currentArtist, 
     currentPath))
        } while (songCursor.moveToNext())
    }
```

**Tried to merge using this code:**

```
fun addAudioVideo(pathvideo: String, String: audioPath, output: String) {
    try {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
          val videoExtractor = MediaExtractor()
          videoExtractor.setDataSource(pathvideo)
          val audioExtractor = MediaExtractor()
          audioExtractor.setDataSource(audioPath)
          Log.d("test", "Video Extractor Track Count " + 
          videoExtractor.trackCount)
          Log.d("test", "Audio Extractor Track Count " + 
          audioExtractor.trackCount)

          val muxer = MediaMuxer(output, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4)

          videoExtractor.selectTrack(0)
          val videoFormat = videoExtractor.getTrackFormat(0)
          val videoTrack = muxer.addTrack(videoFormat)

          audioExtractor.selectTrack(0)
          val audioFormat = audioExtractor.getTrackFormat(0)
          val audioTrack = muxer.addTrack(audioFormat)

          Log.d("test", "Video Format $videoFormat")
          Log.d("test", "Audio Format $audioFormat")

          var sawEOS = false
          var frameCount = 0
          val offset = 100
          val sampleSize = 256 * 1024
          val videoBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize)
          val audioBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(sampleSize)
          val videoBufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()
          val audioBufferInfo = MediaCodec.BufferInfo()

          videoExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC)
          audioExtractor.seekTo(0, MediaExtractor.SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC)
          muxer.start()
          while (!sawEOS) {
                 videoBufferInfo.offset = offset
                 videoBufferInfo.size = 
                 videoExtractor.readSampleData(videoBuf, offset)

                 if (videoBufferInfo.size < 0 || audioBufferInfo.size <  0) {
                     Log.d("test", "saw input EOS.")
                     sawEOS = true
                     videoBufferInfo.size = 0


                  } else {
                     videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = videoExtractor.sampleTime
                     videoBufferInfo.flags = videoExtractor.sampleFlags
                     //videoBufferInfo.flags = MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_SYNC_FRAME;
                     muxer.writeSampleData(videoTrack, videoBuf, 
             videoBufferInfo)
                     videoExtractor.advance()
                     frameCount++
                     Log.d("test", "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video 
            PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " 
            Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + 
            videoBufferInfo.size / 1024)
                     Log.d("test", "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio 
             PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + " Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + audioBufferInfo.size / 1024)

                    }
                }
                var frameCount2 = 0
                val frame = frameCount * 2
                while (frameCount2 < frame) {
                    frameCount2++
                    audioBufferInfo.offset = offset
                    audioBufferInfo.size = 
               audioExtractor.readSampleData(audioBuf, offset)
                    audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs = 30
                    audioBufferInfo.flags = audioExtractor.sampleFlags
                    muxer.writeSampleData(audioTrack, audioBuf, 
                audioBufferInfo)
                    audioExtractor.advance()

                    Log.d("test", "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Video 
                    PresentationTimeUs:" + videoBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + 
                    " Flags:" + videoBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + 
                    videoBufferInfo.size / 1024)
                    Log.d("test", "Frame (" + frameCount + ") Audio 
                    PresentationTimeUs:" + audioBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs + 
                    " Flags:" + audioBufferInfo.flags + " Size(KB) " + 
                    audioBufferInfo.size / 1024)

                }
                muxer.stop()
                muxer.release
     }
  } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d("test", "Mixer Error 1 " + e.message)
  } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("test", "Mixer Error 2 " + e.message)
  }
 }
```

I want to able to successfully merge the video and audio. where the video will play and audio will act as background music.